# JTextArea's append () method doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, swing, file-io, append, jtextarea

We were assigned to create a simple compiler as a homework that will take set of instructions (containing variables, conditions, jumps, etc.) and evaluate them. That's already done, but I thought I'd make my program little bit more… “shiny”, and add the ability to load instructions from a text file, just for the sake of user comfort; however, it seems that the `JTextArea`'s `append ()` method doesn't seem to really like me, as it does exactly nothing. Here's the relevant code:

```java
BufferedReader bufferedReader;
File file;
FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog (new Frame (), "Open File", FileDialog.LOAD);
String line;

fileDialog.setVisible (true);

if (fileDialog.getFile () != null) {
    file = new File (fileDialog.getDirectory () + fileDialog.getFile ());
    input.setText (""); // delete old first

    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file));
        line = bufferedReader.readLine ();

        while (line != null) {
            input.append (line);
            System.out.println (line);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine ();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

(I'm using Awt's FileDialog instead of Swing's JFileChooser because it simply looks better on Mac, as seen in [Apple's official recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html).)

The `input` variable used in this code points to the JTextArea instance. The funny thing is – the file reading part must be working flawlessly, as I can see the file content being written to the standard output thanks to the `System.out.println ()` call within the `while` loop. However, nothing appears in the `JTextArea`, and I've tried all the existing solutions I've found here on StackOverflow – that includes calling the `repaint ()`, `revalidate ()` and `updateUI ()` methods.

What am I missing?

Comment: Side-step the problems using [JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: *"I'm using Awt's FileDialog instead of Swing's JFileChooser because it simply looks better on Mac,.."*  What are you doing for Windows and *nix?  If targeting only the Mac., why use Java rather than ..Cocoa or whatever is the name of the OS X native GUI toolkit?

Comment: *"We were assigned .. a homework .. That's already done, but I thought I'd make my program little bit more… “shiny”"*  I meant to mention this before but got distracted by the technical side of the question.  If it is homework, time is often better spent improving the readability of the source, adding (relevant) comments, or writing tests that prove the code.  Better to submit well written code with no visible bugs, than code with a red stripe and gold stars that breaks, is inefficient & poorly written. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm targeting mostly the Mac platform, using Java simply because I know it slightly better than Objective-C and Cocoa :-) I tried using the JTextComponent.read (Reader, Object) but I'm not sure if I'm [doing it right](https://gist.github.com/3926638), could I kindly ask you to have a look at my code again, please? The issue remains the same, even with this modification, nothing appears in my text area.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's definitely true, but in this class, we don't submit the source code, teacher only wants to see final application. It's probably unusual, but he's got very… relaxed attitude to teaching :-)

Comment: RE. the new code.  Edit it into a new question that is specific to that method.  It should take less than 40 lines of code to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code probably is called on the event handling loop, where you cannot have drawing.
One would normally use

```
final String line = bufferedReader.relineadLine();
// final+local var so usable in Runnable.

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        input.append(line + "\n");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it takes some care where to place the invokeLatere (as looping). Better use @AndrewThompson's solution.