# Why is my textarea not updating?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I've looked at similar threads here on SO, but whatever I do, the `jTextArea` won't update.

If I try something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.getB().getC().size(); i++) {
        jTextArea1.append(a.getB().getC(i).toString()); 
        jTextArea1.update(jTextArea1.getGraphics());
    }
```

I saw someone using `getGraphics` to resolve this problem, but it is not working in my case.

How can I make sure that the `jTextArea` is updated?

I've made sure that there's a value in the string as I print that to the console before trying to append it to the textarea.

Comment: *"I saw someone using `getGraphics` to resolve this problem.."*  Ignore them.  They don't have the faintest idea what they are doing.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly the problem was that I created 2 instances of the GUI and one wasn't visible, so it would always exist behind the GUI that I could see, thus hiding the real problem.

When I found that out the problem was easy to solve. In my parentGUI where I create the other gui's, I now gave these new GUI's an instance of the parentGUI. See:

```
private void dropdownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    if (dropdown.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
        NewFrame newFrame = new NewFrame(this); //the keyword this did the trick
        newFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then in the constructor of NewFrame I catch the instance of the parentGUI:

```
public class NewFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private GUI parentgui;

public NewFrame(GUI parentGUI) {
    initComponents();   
    parentgui = parentGUI;
}
```

And now our problem is solved :) I have only one instance of the parentGUI, and the jTextArea gets filled perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should definitely not call update with the graphics of the textarea. Check [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) in order to understand update/getGraphics.

Check this for a solution: [JTextArea's append () method doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996842/jtextareas-append-method-doesnt-seem-to-work)

If it does not help, try to debug, perhaps you are appending an empty string or something like this.

Comment: Well, the string is deff not empty. I print that out in the console. But it doesn't matter what I use, textarea or a textfield, or a combobox, the information doesn't ever make it to the GUI

Comment: The try SwingUtilities.invokeLater as suggested by the link. Or call paintImmediately on the jtextarea, giving the dimensions of the textare as arguments

Comment: PaintImmediately does nothing, and the invokeLater method causes the index parameter in getC(i) not to be recognized anymore :(

Comment: @Ibalazscs do you have any more ideas?

Comment: You need to declare the i variable as final.

Answer (score 2):

Swing Components should be updated in [EDT.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.getB().getC().size(); i++) {

final int value = i;

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        jTextArea1.append(a.getB().getC(value).toString()); 
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I've seen more people posting this as a solution, however this causes the index parameter in getC(i) from the for loop not to be recognized anymore.

Comment: @Forza : Just inside for loop use, `final int value = i;` now use `value` as a parameter to `getC(value)`, instead of `i` :-)

Comment: @nlcE cOw, the problem with  i  is solved now, but there's still nothing in the textarea :(

Comment: @Forza : More information is actually required to answer this question in a better way ( The context in which you using this loop ). Please try to provide one [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) :-)

Answer (score 1):

`jTextArea.append` should work. Maybe the update to the text area is blocked by some GUI action in the Swing Thread?